# Does anybody know what app this icon in the menu bar belongs to?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

[image: It's a double arrow]

[image: This is what pops up when I click on the icon]

Also nothing shows up when I type into the search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menulet belongs to VMware Fusion. It's a start menu similar to the Windows start menu and usually shows apps installed in a/the Windows VM.

You can turn it on temporarily/on/off in: VMware -> Preferences -> General

[image]